# Fi-ware IDM - Oauth2 php client configuration

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, fiware

I'm trying to use the FiWare [Identity Management - KeyRock](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/identity-management-keyrock) that provides a Oauth 2.0 login. I have configured my app in the Fiware web page to set the url and callback url and I have got my client ID and my password.

Now I'm trying to use the API with a simple PHP client Oauth2.0 library. I've choosen [this](https://github.com/fkooman/php-oauth-client). It looks very easy to use, but I have a problem:

When I open my web, I'm correctly redirected to the fi-ware login web page, but once i logged, I'm not redirected to my web page callback page, I continue in the fi-ware labs web page.

That's my code:

index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use fkooman\OAuth\Client\Guzzle6Client;
use fkooman\OAuth\Client\ClientConfig;
use fkooman\OAuth\Client\SessionStorage;
use fkooman\OAuth\Client\Api;
use fkooman\OAuth\Client\Context;

$clientConfig = new ClientConfig(
    array(
        'authorize_endpoint' => 'https://account.lab.fi-ware.org',
        'client_id' => 'my_client_id',
        'client_secret' => 'my_secret',
        'token_endpoint' => 'http://estebanxabi.miwp.eu/otros/callback.php',
    )
);

$tokenStorage = new SessionStorage();
$httpClient = new Guzzle6Client();
$api = new Api('foo', $clientConfig, $tokenStorage, $httpClient);

$context = new Context('sampleEmail', array('authorizations'));

$accessToken = $api->getAccessToken($context);
if (false === $accessToken) {
    /* no valid access token available, go to authorization server */
    header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
    header('Location: '.$api->getAuthorizeUri($context));
    exit;
}

echo 'Access Token: '.$accessToken->getAccessToken();
```

and callback.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use fkooman\OAuth\Client\Guzzle6Client;
use fkooman\OAuth\Client\ClientConfig;
use fkooman\OAuth\Client\SessionStorage;
use fkooman\OAuth\Client\Callback;

$clientConfig = new ClientConfig(
    array(
        'authorize_endpoint' => 'https://account.lab.fi-ware.org',
        'client_id' => 'client_ide',
        'client_secret' => 'seceret',
        'token_endpoint' => 'http://estebanxabi.miwp.eu/otros/callback.php',
    )
);

try {
    $tokenStorage = new SessionStorage();
    $httpClient = new Guzzle6Client();

    $cb = new Callback('foo', $clientConfig, $tokenStorage, $httpClient);
    $cb->handleCallback($_GET);

    header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
    header('Location: http://localhost/fkooman/php-oauth-client/example/simple6/index.php');
    exit;
} catch (fkooman\OAuth\Client\Exception\AuthorizeException $e) {
    // this exception is thrown by Callback when the OAuth server returns a
    // specific error message for the client, e.g.: the user did not authorize
    // the request
    die(sprintf('ERROR: %s, DESCRIPTION: %s', $e->getMessage(), $e->getDescription()));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // other error, these should never occur in the normal flow
    die(sprintf('ERROR: %s', $e->getMessage()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never use that library, but taking a look... are you sure "token_endpoint" is correctly configured? It is not the same the token endpoint (/oauth2/token) than the callback URL.

BR